# Trying to get the right final format in an Array from a Map, to update using a REST API, but can't quite JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to format some data to batch update using Woocommerce REST API.

Target array format:

```
update: [
 {
  id: 1,
  app: 'string1string2string3'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  app: 'string2'
 }, 
 {
  id: 3,
  app: 'string2'
 },
 {
  id: 5,
  app: 'string2'
 }
]
```

Reproducible example

```js
arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  app: 'string1'
}, {
  id: 1,
  app: 'string2'
}, {
  id: 1,
  app: 'string3'
}, {
  id: 2,
  app: 'string2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  app: 'string2'
}, {
  id: 5,
  app: 'string2'
}];

let a = new Map();

arr1.forEach((e) => {
  if (a.get(e.id)) {
    a.get(e.id).app += e.app;
  } else {
    a.set(e.id, e)
  }
})

const finalizado = Array.from(a)
console.log(finalizado);

var temporary, chunk = 100;
for (let i = 0; i < finalizado.length; i += chunk) {
  temporary = finalizado.slice(i, i + chunk);
  var payloadUp = {
    update: temporary
  };
  console.log(payloadUp);
}
```

This is a reproducible example, my first try was to just form an Array from the Map:

```
const finalizado = Array.from(a)
```

That didn't work, then I tried to give it some format:

```
const finalizado = Array.from(a, [key, value] => {
  return ([key]: value);
}
```

But I'm out of my depth I think, I can't get my head around the formatting.

Comment: What do you mean "that didn't work"?  Did you get an error?

Comment: Oh no, I mean I didn't get the right format, the code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Use `reduce()` and `Object.values()` can set a target array like you want:

```js
arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  app: 'string1'
}, {
  id: 1,
  app: 'string2'
}, {
  id: 1,
  app: 'string3'
}, {
  id: 2,
  app: 'string2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  app: 'string2'
}, {
  id: 5,
  app: 'string2'
}];

const arrayHashmap = arr1.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.id] ? obj[item.id].app = obj[item.id].app.concat(item.app) : (obj[item.id] = { ...item });
  return obj;
}, {});

const mergedArray = Object.values(arrayHashmap);

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: It's the correct answer! I wished for a simpler approach though since I'm rather new to programming and reduce is a bit advanced for me, but still works 100%. Thank you!